# Web Api 2 bad request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, bad-request

Im a beginner with Web api and Im trying to setup a simple owin selfhosted service that Im trying out.

I've been searching stackoverflow and other places for a while now, but I cant seem to find anything obviously wrong.

The problem I have is that I get a bad request response everytime I try to call my service.

The controller looks like this:

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/ndtdocument")]
public class NDTDocumentsController : ApiController, INDTDocumentsController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var document = Program.NDTServerSession.GetNextNDTDocument(DateTime.Today);
        if (document == null)
            return null;

        return Ok(document);


    }

    [Route("")]

    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] NDTDocument ndtDocument)
    {
        try
        {
            Program.NDTServerSession.AddNDTDocument(ndtDocument);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);

        }


    }





}
```

And the client looks like this:

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {


         AddNDTDocument(@"C:\Testing.txt");


    }



    private static void AddNDTDocument(string centralserverPath)
    {

        var client = GetServerClient();
        NDTDocument document = new NDTDocument();
        var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("ndtdocument", document).Result;


    }

    static HttpClient GetServerClient()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/api/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        return client;



    }
```

I can see when I debug it that the request uri is infact http://localhost:9000/api/ndtdocument

But the response is allways bad request and I have a breakpoint in the controller and it is never invoked.

Everytime I try to do something with web apis I Always run into some weird (but simple problem).

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Web API will decide your route based on your method names. Since you have added `[RoutePrefix("api/ndtdocument")]` on class level this will be the route to your controller. When web api looks for an action it will match on method names, so in your case your actual route would be `http://localhost:9000/api/ndtdocument/post`.

When trying to decide what `http method` that a specific action requires web api will check your method names and methods starting with `post` will be `http post`, `get` will be `http get` etc.

So lets say we would instead call our method `PostData`, for starters we could remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute. Our route would now be `http://localhost:9000/api/ndtdocument/postdata`. Let's now say that we want our path to be just `/data`. We would then first rename our method to Data, but now web api does not know what http method we want to invoke this method with, thats why we add the `[HttpPost]` attribute.

**Edit after reading your comment**

```
[Route("{id:int}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)

[Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] NDTDocument ndtDocument)
```

Comment: Ok, so what should I do to be able to call my endpoint with the post verb like Im doing?
I want to be able to use a Get verb to retrieve an ndtdocument (with a id as parameter) as a next step for instance.

Comment: @Erik83 What about setting that route on your method `[Route("/{id}]` along with the `[HttpPost]` attribute.

Comment: I dont Think you understood my comment.
I want to be able to get a ndtdocument using client.GetAsAsync<NDTDocument>("ndtdocument/{id}")
and I want to be able to post (upload) a ndtdocument using 
client.PostAsAsync("ndtdocument").
Isnt this how you mostly do it?
Is there a way to disable the routinggeneration from looking at method names?

Comment: You have a default configuration of routes, in your web api config, which looks something like api/{controller}/{action}/{id}. You could modify this to be just api/{controller}/{id}.

Comment: The default routing is api/{controller}/{id}" as far as I can see. 
Its being set like this

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: @Erik83 Check my edit, that should give you disired behaviour

Comment: @Erik83 provided that you keep your current routeprefix

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101404/discussion-between-simon-karlsson-and-erik83).

Answer (score 1):

Okey, after nearly going seriously insane. I found the problem. 
I forgot to reference webapi.webhost and then system.web.

After this Everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You must use route tags and call this way http://localhost:9000/api/get or http://localhost:9000/api/post

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/ndtdocument")]
    public class NDTDocumentsController : ApiController, INDTDocumentsController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("get")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            var document = Program.NDTServerSession.GetNextNDTDocument(DateTime.Today);
            if (document == null)
                return null;

            return Ok(document);


        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("post")]
        public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] NDTDocument ndtDocument)
        {
            try
            {
                Program.NDTServerSession.AddNDTDocument(ndtDocument);
                return Ok();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);

            }   
        }
    }
```

for more infromation pls check this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)